# Uploading an image using multi-part and Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload an image into my backend server. A new record gets created but no images are ever uploaded:

```
func uploadDish(dish:Dish, completionHandler: ((AnyObject?, ErrorType?) -> Void)){
    let urlString = "http://backend.com/v1/dish"
    SwiftSpinner.show("Uploading Dish...")
    Alamofire.upload(
        .POST,
        urlString,
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

            if let image = self.image {
                if let imageData : NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1){
                    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "file", fileName: "testesttest.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                }
            }
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "foo".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name :"name")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "bar".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name :"address")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "1".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name :"priceRange")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "\(234)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name :"lat")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "\(234)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name :"lng")
        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                print(upload.debugDescription)
                break
            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                break
            }
        }
    )
    SwiftSpinner.hide()
}
```

It works in Postman:

[image]

Comment: Have you any error? Can you post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually correct, found out the bug was in the back end.

**The above way is how you post images**